# No able to change some word in English version of my site

Tags: view, block, frontend, magento-1.9, multilingual

I've an e-commerce site in Magento 1.9 with two version: English and French. I've to change some words in both English version and in the French. For example, in the English version, I've to change word "BAG" in the homepage menu.

I've to replace "BAG" with "SHOPPING BAG" but, inserting string "BAG", "SHOPPING BAG" (or "bag","shopping bag", or "Bag", "Shopping bag") into translate.csv of the theme (in the English folder) any change is shown in the frontend. Activating path hints for the English version I notice that the phtml file that builds the block that contains this menu is the following:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php echo $this->getContentType() ?>" />
<title><?php echo $this->getTitle()?></title>
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getDescription()) ?>" />
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getKeywords()) ?>" />
<meta name="robots" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getRobots()) ?>" />
<link rel="icon" href="<?php echo $this->getFaviconFile(); ?>" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo $this->getFaviconFile(); ?>" type="image/x-icon" />
<?php
    $currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
    if (preg_match('/^https/', $currentUrl)) {
        $currentUrl = str_replace('https://', 'http://', $currentUrl);
    }

    $exclusions = array(
        'checkout/',
        'customer/account/'
    );
    $regexUrl = '/^' . str_replace(array('/', '.'), array('\\/', '\\.'), Mage::getBaseUrl() . '(?:(?:' . implode(')|(?:', $exclusions) . '))') . '/';
    if (!preg_match($regexUrl, $currentUrl)) {
        echo '<link rel="canonical" href="' . $currentUrl . '" />';
    }
?>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var BLANK_URL = '<?php echo $this->helper('core/js')->getJsUrl('blank.html') ?>';
    var BLANK_IMG = '<?php echo $this->helper('core/js')->getJsUrl('spacer.gif') ?>';
//]]>
</script>
<![endif]-->

<?php echo $this->getCssJsHtml() ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>
<?php echo $this->getIncludes() ?>
```

I think that there are some function (may be getHtmlChild()) that overwrites my translation because other words are translated adding new strings into traslate.csv.

Which file or function I've to change to see "shopping bag" in the frontend of my site? Why some words are changed with translate.csv and others not? Can you help me, please? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

First, all strings in the translation files are casesensitive.

When I look for a word to translate for example **"add to my cart"** then I usually do like this:
Open a terminal and go to the root of your magento shop and run:

```
cd app
git grep  "add to my cart" | grep csv
```

This gets all the hits from all your translation files in your entire project.
My result looks like this:

```
design/frontend/fortis/eke/locale/sv_SE/translate.csv:1:﻿"Add to Cart","add to my cart"
locale/sv_SE/Mage_Catalog.csv:33:"Add to Cart","add to my cart"
```

In the result, first you se the path to the file and then the translation.
In my example the string was already translated. But now you know exactly what the base string is. Use this in you own translation file.

If you don´t get a hit in the translation files then the word or sentence might come from a cms-block or cms-page. To search for it there you have to connect to your SQL server and run some querys like this (one at the time):

```
select * from cms_block where content like '%add to my cart%';
select * from cms_page where content like '%add to my cart%';
```

From the result you can see what the block or page with the string is named. Go the backend and edit it.